# model posted back has null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this in my controller, it it being posted to on a form submit.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(OrderDetailsViewModel thisWindowModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(thisWindowModel);
            }
```

When model staie is invalid and I return the model back to the view Im getting an object reference not set exception pointing at this line:

```
<h2>Order Details:@Model.Style.Name</h2>
```

I've inspected the "thisWindowModel" as it enters the httppost method, and style is indeed null there.... but why is it doing that?/how to fix?

**Update**

I have tried adding hiddenfor now too, and even changed my model to to just use stylename as a string but it still fails throws a null refference exception.

```
 @if(Model==null)
        {
            <h2>model null</h2>

        }else{

            if(Model.StyleName==null)
            {
                <h2>model style null</h2>
            }

        <h2>Order Details:@Model.StyleName</h2>
        }
```

at the last '`}`'

Comment: You should be able to tell us. Is `Style` ever initialized?

Comment: Where are your `@Html.EditFor` or `<input` html elements?  How do you expect your html to use [the post back model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form)?  MVC does not inherently do some type of html/http magic to allow form posts to send values back to the server.

Comment: can you post your whole form

Answer (score 1):

in your form, add an `Html.HiddenFor()` for your model item.  As you have it, it has no idea how to recreate `Model.Style.Name` when rebuilding the model on postback.

Answer (score 1):

you have to post the `@Model.Style.Name` in the **form post**, you have just used it in your view in heading tag but you need to post all model properties in a **form** , otherwise it will be posted `null`

Use `@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Style.Name)` in your form so that this property value is posted in form.